# Cosmos DB Query Array value using SQL

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I have several JSON files with below structure in my cosmos DB.

```
[
{
    "USA":  {
        "Applicable": "Yes",
        "Location": {
            "City": [
                "San Jose",
                "San Diego"
                ]
        }
    }
}]
```

I want to query all the results/files that has the array value of city = "San Diego".

I've tried the below sql queries

```
SELECT DISTINCT *
FROM c["USA"]["Location"]
WHERE ["City"] IN ('San Diego')

SELECT DISTINCT *
FROM c["USA"]["Location"]
WHERE ["City"] = 'San Diego'

SELECT c 
FROM c JOIN d IN c["USA"]["Location"]
WHERE d["City"] = 'San Diego'
```

I'm getting the results as **0 - 0**

Comment: I'm not sure why azure-data-explorer tag was removed. I am using the Azure Data Explorer to query the cosmos db. can i add it back @Yoni L.

Comment: to my understanding, this question has nothing to do with the Big Data analytics platform named "Azure Data Explorer", rather it discusses a query run against an entirely different Azure service, named "Cosmos DB".

Comment: Correct - Azure Data Explorer has nothing to do with the "Data Explorer" tab in Cosmos DB; it's related to Kusto. It's been correctly removed. However, the other tags are problematic too - this shouldn't be tagged with `sql` - I fixed this. Final note: I believe you meant to say you have some documents in a Cosmos DB collection, not "JSON files," correct?

Answer (score 3):

You need to query data from your entire document, where your `USA.Location.City` array contains an item. For example:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM c
WHERE ARRAY_CONTAINS (c.USA.Location.City, "San Jose")
```

This will give you what you're trying to achieve.

Note: You have a slight anti-pattern in your schema, using "USA" as the key, which means you can't easily query all the location names. You should replace this with something like:

```json
{
    "Country": "USA",
    "CountryMetadata":  {
        "Applicable": "Yes",
        "Location": {
            "City": [
                "San Jose",
                "San Diego"
                ]
        }
    }
}
```

This lets you query all the different countries. And the query above would then need only a slight change:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM c
WHERE c.Country = "USA
AND ARRAY_CONTAINS (c.CountryMetadata.Location.City, "San Jose")
```

Note that the query now works for any country, and you can pass in country value as a parameter (vs needing to hardcode the country name into the query because it's an actual key name).

Tl;dr don't put values as your keys.